# SPServices Unique choice field not giving list entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices

This one may sound weird but any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using GetListItems of SPServices and one of the fields is a Choice field that has to be unique (which I believe is causing the issue). Here is the code:

```
$().SPServices({
      operation: method, 
      async: false,
      listName: "Content", 
      CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Section' /><FieldRef Name='Content' /><FieldRef Name='Order' /></ViewFields>", 
      CAMLQuery: "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Order' Ascending='True'/></OrderBy><Where><Neq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>0</Value></Neq></Where></Query>",
      completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
           $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var cont = $(this).attr('ows_Content')==undefined?cont = "": cont = $(this).attr('ows_Content');
                var object={
                     title:$(this).attr('ows_Title'),
                     content:cont,
                     order:$(this).attr('ows_Order')
                }
                pages.push(object);
                console.log(object.order)
           });
      }
 });
```

The console log details the object.order as:

```
"100.000000000000"
"200.000000000000"
"300.000000000000"
etc...
```

At first I thought It was just pulling through a float error but I could get around that until I noticed that the order choice in the list does not match the selection.

For Example, the list item which order is 1 (in the List View), on the page pulls through as order 200.000000000000

Im not sure why this is, can anyone help?

Comment: So I just deleted an entry and added it back into the list, even though I selected order:1 it is pulling through to the page as order:2900.0000000. Which is the highest in the list. Is it treating it like the ID?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so found the value I wanted, as it turns out there was a secondary attr called `ows_Order0` which had the selected value in it.